# No Singles Allowed

Tags: code-golf, math, restricted-source, geometry

This is a fairly simple challenge.

Write a program that computes the distance between two points on a 2D plane. However, you can't use any functions or operators (referred to here as symbols) that are 1 character long.

**Examples:**

- `-=`, `+=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, etc. are allowed.
- `||`, `&&`, `--`, `++` are allowed as well.
- `+`, `-`, `/`, `*` are not allowed.
- `f(x)` is not allowed, but `fn(x)` is.
- `S 5 4` is not allowed, but `SUM 5 4` is.
- `if(lol==lel)` is allowed.
- Simply putting two separate single-character operators one after the other is not allowed, eg. `!!(true)` isn't allowed.

**Exceptions:**

- Single semicolons or the equivalent are allowed, e.g. `foo();`, as long as they are being used as an end-of-command symbol.
- Commas (`,`) and periods (`.`) are allowed.
- Parentheses (`()`) and other symbols that are used in such a way to require a second match are allowed. Examples:

  - `foo();` is allowed, as is `foo(x);`.
  - `[5,6]` is allowed.
  - `"strings"` are allowed.
  - `for(i+=5;;i++){}` is allowed
  - `if(1<2 && 2>3)` is not allowed, as the symbols are being interpreted as greater than and less than symbols, and so do not require the other.
  - `([{<>}])` is allowed.
  - `][` is not allowed, as the symbols do not match.
  - Essentially, the interpreter/compiler/etc.(?) should recognize the symbols as matching.

**Specifications:**

- Whitespace does not count for the single character rule, e.g. `this == that` and `this  ==that` etc. are both allowed.
- Standard rules for loopholes etc. apply.
- Input can be in any reasonable format of two points. Examples:

  - `[{x:0,y:0},{x:9,y:786}]`*
  - `[[5,4],[6,8]]`
  - `"54,37,68,9760"`
  - `new Point(0,0), new Point(5,6)`
  - `["34,56","23,98657"]`
  - etc.
- Output should be a double or equivalent with 5 significant digits.
- **No eval!**
- This is code-golf, so shortest allowed and functioning code wins!

*You would have to construct the objects a different way, as colons are single symbols.

Good luck without being able to use the `=` operator! :P

**Edit:** Imaginary 5 kudo points for not using a built-in.

Comment: "f(x) is not allowed, but fn(x) is", aren't `(`, `x` and `)` all one character long? You also seem to be missing a winning criterion.

Comment: you used variables with 1 character long, is that acceptable?

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Variables that are 1 character long are good to go, as long as it's not a function.

Comment: @MartinEnder Oops, forgot the code-golf tag.... :P Parentheses do not count, I'll add that into my question.

Comment: what about `:` ?

Comment: @Feathercrown, questions like this are **very** hard to get right... What about "special operators"? You allow `()`, but what about `@`? `.`, `:`, `=` and so on?

Comment: This seems awfully language specific. In CJam, `.` is a sort of meta-operator that combines with the next token into a single new operator, so that `.-` is element-wise subtraction. Is that one two-character symbol or are those two one-character symbols?

Comment: Restricted source questions are notoriously difficult to get right, because the tend to make many language assumptions. For example here, the language Whitespace has no effective restrictions. For future challenges, I recommend posting to the [Sandbox](http://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where you can get meaningful feedback and iron out details before posting a challenge to Main.

Comment: What about strings? `"foo"`

Comment: I've clarified those questions. @StewieGriffin The whole point is that special operators are restricted; no, those are not allowed.

Comment: @MartinEnder The cjam example is interesting... I guess that would count as one two-character operator.

Comment: i would like to add `dist s t=sum(map(**2)(zipWith subtract s t))**0.5` but the `on hold` status seems to prevent me from doing that.

Comment: @RomanCzyborra the `=` symbol is not allowed

Comment: Are all strings allowed? In python: `eval("a+b")` it's a valid string, but it will be executed as code

Comment: You say that semicolons are allowed as line ending symbols but `for(i+=5;;i++){} ` is disallowed? The semicolons in a for loop are line ending symbols. Just because they commonly don't have a newline after them does not mean that they are some type of operator.

Comment: Bigram/Trigram allowed?

Comment: Well there goes every 2d esolang :(

Comment: @WheatWizard Wait, the are? I thought they were their own thing.

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Good catch. Eval is not allowed.

Comment: Should've added a "no built-ins" restriction. Oh well.

Comment: The list of things which are unclear is too long to write because I'd certainly miss a few, but includes: 1. What is a "*symbol*"? 2. Is `--` allowed when it's two separate stack-based subtractions? In general it's not clear whether the rules are meant to apply on a syntax level or on a source level (although it is clear that you didn't think about any languages outside the ALGOL family) -- and in fact they seem to be mixed together. 3. It's not obvious why you need to explicitly allow `"'([{<>}])'"`, given that it's a string. 4. The rules on input are rendered irrelevant by the ban on eval.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. A symbol is an operator. I've added that into the question for clarity. 2. `--` as 2 `-`s is not allowed under this rule as it is 2 separate single-character operators, which are illegal in this challenge. 3. Not really a problem, since it's just another example of something that's valid, but I "fixed" it anyways. 4. I'm not sure I understand, please clarify.

Comment: @WheatWizard It appears that you are right. Fixin' it.

Comment: @ETHProductions, TaylorScott, DownChristopher, and powelles: Can you please explain what exactly is unclear?

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
print abs(input().__sub__(input()))
```

Example input for points (5,4) and (6,8):

```python
5+4j
6+8j
4.12310562562
```

or:

```python
complex(5,4)
complex(6,8)
4.12310562562
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19QlJlXopCYVKyRmVdQWqKhqRcfX1yaFB8P42tq/v9vqm2SxWWmbZH1NS9fNzkxOSMVAA)

Comment: @nimi `.` and `,` are allowed, however `=` is not, which is going to be the hard part for most languages.

Comment: @nini fixed it, as `()` and `.` are now allowed

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
EuclideanDistance
```

A function invoked like `EuclideanDistance[{5,4}, {6,8}]`. Works in other dimensions as well.

Mathematica and its long command names thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 10 bytes

```
Math.hypot
```

Returns a function that does the job. For 13 bytes, I can do it using only paired puncutation:

```
Math['hypot']
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 33 bytes

```
cd<-function(a,b)dist(rbind(a,b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#HccxDoAgDAXQ67RJGVBHb2Ic4Bdjl2IQj@6MiW97A7qG43F0q05JMqvdnVo21788rmbeCUqgKBMLaJaFeYs7j9drQMJZPg)

## R, 26 bytes

```
dist(rbind(scan(),scan()))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, 20 bytes

```
abs(diff(input('')))
```

Takes input on the form: `[5+4j, 6+8j]`.

Anonymous functions can't be used since `@` is a single character. It takes a vector with two complex numbers as input, calculated the difference, and takes the absolute value.